# Radio button is not displaying right value

Tags: android, button, radio-button

In my coding m having three buttons. i am getting the selected button is id and used it for comparison. But it first automatically displays the default selected button's id before clicking the button.

```
rdgp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                counter++;
                if (counter > 5 || counter >= anarray.size()) {
                    Toast.makeText(testActivity.this, "" + score, 2000).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(testActivity.this, Badge.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Score", score);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return;
                }

                rb1.setText(anarray.get(counter));
                rb2.setText(an1array.get(counter));
                rb3.setText(an2array.get(counter));
                rb4.setText(an3array.get(counter));
                rb5.setText(an4array.get(counter));
                int ans = 0;
                if (checkedId == R.id.radio0) {
                    ans = 1;
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio1) {
                    ans = 2;
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio2) {
                    ans = 3;
                } else if (checkedId == R.id.radio3) {
                    ans = 4;
                }

                Toast.makeText(testActivity.this, "" + ans, 2000).show();
                if (ans == anarray.get(counter))
                    ;
                {
                    score = score + 1;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the id of checked `radiobutton` use `group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()`.Returns the identifier of the selected radio button in this group. Upon empty selection, the returned value is -1.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line, in your XML for all radio buttons.

```
 android:checked="false"
```

Comment: it is working for first set of data. When onclick moves to next set of data clicked button in first set of data is showing and that value is selected for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting default value from radio buttons then check in our layout file weather you used android:checked = "true".If this is the state then change it to false.